# lite-server not providing .js file inside /js folder - browser doesnt request /js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, lite-server

I'm running a `lite-server` with `npm run lite`

My jQuery file is being loaded normally, and my css inside the css folder too, but the browser do not even make the GET request for the `main.js` file.

the `main.js` file is inside the /js folder as `style.css` as in /css folder

Am I missing something?

this is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" scr="js/main.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        test
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** -> Just realized also that the browser isn't making the GET request for this file. And also if i make a request directly to the js file, the server returns it.

[image: index.html request]
[image: main.js request]

And the `npm run lite` running:

```
$ npm run lite

> sdfa@1.0.0 lite C:\temp\nodeIntro
> lite-server

Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
** browser-sync config **
{ injectChanges: false,
  files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
  watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
  server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
[BS] Access URLs:
 ------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.1.4:3000
 ------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.1.4:3001
 ------------------------------------
[BS] Serving files from: ./
[BS] Watching files...
17.03.11 12:52:27 304 GET /index.html
17.03.11 12:52:27 304 GET /node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
17.03.11 12:52:27 304 GET /node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js
17.03.11 12:52:27 304 GET /css/style.css
```

Comment: Either you need a task scheduler like webpack to copy the main.js file in the js folder or you need to manualy do.

Comment: the `main.js` file is inside the /js folder as `style.css` as in /css folder...

Comment: i have added the anwer

Comment: thanks man.... I'm feelling the dumbest in the world now

Comment: not like that, Its a common typo

Comment: I should have noticed that. but thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missstyped the **src** by **scr**

error

correct

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```